# How could I make a vulnerable WordPress site that resets itself every 15 minutes?

Tags: web-hosting, wordpress, cron

I would like to add a vulnerable WordPress website hosted using docker as a capture-the-flag challenge to my website. Is there a way to reset it every 15 minutes to it's initial state? Are there any other security measures I should take? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I fear that this question is overly broad (ie "other security measures I should take".

It is fairly trivial to set up a Wordpress site to automatically reset - just blow the live site and database away and replace with a known good site.  Thats all there is to it.   Of-course, as you are using Docker, just replace the docker container.

You may want to also change the salts in wp-config.php and also the password to connect to the database if you don't want a compromise to mean a leg up on future attempts.

It would not seem to make sense to ask "what other security measures you should take" if the goal is to have a vulnerable site.  You can apply all sorts of security measures.   If you are wanting to limit hacking paths, limit what is available on the system - ie no SSH access, locking down what can be accessed via PHP [ possibly prevent execution of certain commands like eval - there is a large list of these ].